# Query regarding phase of analytic signal.

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Using the following matlab commands, phase of analytic signal can be obtained.

sig_a = hilbert ( sig ) ;
ph = atan(angle(sig_a)) ;

As for as my understanding is angle(sig_a) will give phase of sig_a. I am not understanding why tan inverse of angle(sig_a) is required? Please help.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I can't see why you would do $\arctan$ on an angle and not a ratio.

Comment: Source : atan(angle(sig_a)) was used in one of the function of the project I am working. Can we conclude that this is a mistake?

Comment: I would think so. The phase of a signal $x$, at least as understood by every book I have ever read and every person I have ever worked with, is $\arctan \left( \mathfrak{I} \{ x \} / \mathfrak{R} \{ x \} \right)$, which is what `angle` returns.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, applying  `atan` after `angle` makes no sense, since the `angle` command outputs the phase in radians. It would be appropriate  to have either

- `ph = angle(sig_a);`
- `ph = unwrap(angle(sig_a));`

[Unwrap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html) is a useful command that eliminates unnecessary breaks in the phase plot by picking a continuous branch of argument.